# What does やさぐれ mean?

Tags: words, meaning, slang

I believe it has something to do with bullying.
Also, I think I heard it as a verb: やさぐれる
I can't seem to find much information about it. Is it slang?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that most Japanese-to-English dictionaries have an entry for this (e.g., JMDict: http://tangorin.com/general/yasagure), and I'm not sure I can elaborate much more than what's on there:

> noun:
>
> 1. running away from home —Slang.
> 2. runaway (child)

If you're interested in the etymology, I recommend checking out [the gogen-allguide entry for やさぐれる](http://gogen-allguide.com/ya/yasagureru.html).

Comment: Yes, I thought it was that but a Japanese friend tried to explain it and made it sound like it was related to somebody being hit rather than running away.

Comment: @DaleyPaley I'm not sure what he could be talking about. Even 大辞林 has no mention of hitting: ①〔本来は不良仲間の隠語。「やさ」は「家」，「ぐれ」は「はずれる」の意〕 家出をすること。また，家出人。②〔「ぐれ」の部分から連想した誤用によって広がった用法〕 投げやりになること。 Unless perhaps you misheard your friend who was actually saying 投げる rather than 殴る?

Comment: OK, I guess it was just a misunderstanding on my part, or perhaps a localised vernacular. I will ask him again when I seehim. Anyway, thanks for your help.